# How to stop jQuery animation and resume later?

Tags: jquery, animation

How to stop an animation and resume later with jQuery?

For example, I've this and i want to avoid the slide-up if the user is dragging another item.

**[example here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/GUK5w/1/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here [jQuery stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

That'll do what you need.

**Edit**: I've had a look at the code and I think i've got it.
I've added some boolean variables to check against to determine whether the a slideUp should occur.

```
$(function() {
    var item = $("#items .item");
    var slider = $(".slider");
    var droppable = $("#favorite");
    var dropComplete = false;
    var dragging = false;

    item.draggable({
        opacity: 0.75,
        helper: "clone",
        start: function() {
            // set variables for drag and drop.
            dropComplete = false;
            dragging = true;
            slider.slideDown().clearQueue();
        },
        stop: function(){
            // drag has been abandoned.
            dragging = false;

            setTimeout(function () { 
             if (dragging === false && dropComplete === false){
                 slider.clearQueue().slideUp();
             } 
             }, 3000);

            }

    }).disableSelection();

    droppable.droppable({
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        drop: function(event, ui) {  
            $('.last.item').replaceWith($(ui.draggable).clone().addClass('last'));
            //alert(ui.draggable.attr('id').substring(6));
            // drop is complete.
            dropComplete = true;

         setTimeout(function () { 
             if (dropComplete === true){
                 slider.clearQueue().slideUp();
             } 
         }, 3000);

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: yeah but that stops the animation, i need to start it again after 3 seconds of inactivity.

Comment: Sorry about the delay. New Year and what not.... I've added some code which seems to solve your problem.

Comment: Oh thanks for this. I've tested it but apparently ig you drag one item and drop it, wait two seconds and drag & drop anotehr ot the timer doesn't restart, after one second it slides up again.

Comment: I'll have another look once I get the chance. I think i'm on the right path though.

Comment: I had another crack at it seems to be working now. http://www.jsfiddle.net/GUK5w/3/

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can use the jQuery .stop() function.

[jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: yeah but that stops the animation, i need to start it again after 3 seconds of inactivity.

Comment: I believe that you could set a timer - and when it hits 3 seconds (or 3000 milliseconds) fire an event to call the .animate() action.

Comment: Here's a link regarding using timers / delay if you aren't familiar with them. http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: If you look the code you will see that i'm using delay so...i know them. but giving me only links you aren't helping so much.

Comment: Sorry Sein, I was on a phone so it isn't very easy to look at the example. I believe that I am a little confused as to exactly what you are going for. I noticed that after your slide up occurs, if you are dragging another item, the animation doesn't slide up - Perhaps I need more clarification as to what you are looking for.

Comment: if you look a the code the slideup occurs only when the drag stops or when the ittem is dropped. In other words if the itrem is dropped anywhere out of the box is like the user has cancelled the action. The problem is that i need to keep the div displayed if the cuser has "cancelled" the action and is dragging anotehr item to be dropped